# Gender Neutral Salutation /Honorific

Tags: gender-neutral, grammatical-gender

In the context of addressing an unknown individual in an email/letter, how does one include persons belonging to the broad gender spectrum? 
For instance, in binary terms *Dear Mam/Sir* was the norm for a while. What would be the appropriate/ widely accepted way to address an audience which could be non-binary, to ensure that any receiver is not offended?

As a specific scenario, assume that I am writing to a non-academic committee, therefore, the usage of First Name is ruled out ( being too personal), also I cannot use words such as Dear Professor (since the occupation is not Professor).
Note that I am aware of previous (old) questions on [gender neutral words in a letter](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/dear-sir-or-madam-versus-to-whom-it-may-concern) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43608/what-is-the-correct-way-to-greet-a-specific-person-when-only-their-business-titl). Do we have any new words in current usage?
While I agree that "To whomsoever it may concern" may be used, as mentioned in one of the questions:

> addressing the person by his/her title is a little more specific and evidence that you've put some thought into it.

Comment: @whiskeychief, while it is politically correct, in the context of writing an important email, it may not give the desired first impression. Any references are welcome.

Comment: Consider "Dear Colleague".   [link](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_g&page=9tZXuAe4oZYs.html#zz9tZXuAe4oZYs)

Comment: @whiskeychief , yes, but it seems like a specific thing isnt it? Suppose I am writing to a group of Managers or a some Deans in an institution, do we have an answer that would be suitable for these scenarios?

Comment: "Dear members of the search committee" [link](https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/gender-inclusive-language/),  Dear managers;  Dear deans;  "Greetings" [link](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/letter-salutations-and-greetings-2059709);  Greetings from Peoria;  or eliminate the salutation [link](http://www.gov.pe.ca/photos/original/GenderGuideline.pdf) especially if in email.

Comment: "Dear members of the search committee" is an excellent suggestion, or use "Dear head official of the search committee" for an "individual".

Comment: Thank you for the useful replies. If you would be kind enough to post the replies as separate answers, I could accept them.

Comment: Why not just adress everyone with a cheerful “hello?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've ruled out 'to whom it may concern' I would probably go for

> Dear Committee Member(s)

As that it what they all are, and is relevant to the letter you are writing.

(s) depending on if it's a letter to each of them, or a singular letter to the goup.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments "**Dear members of the search committee**" would be an excellent suggestion, or use "**Dear head official of the search committee**" for an "individual".

You might also use "**Dear honorable search committee**" to emphasize the "honorific" aspect of your question. You can decide.